# I'm Initializing two NSArrays. Why might one work and the other fail?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

I am trying to initialize two NSArrays with the following code

```
self.fillingTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Ham",@"Turkey",@"Peanut Butter", @"Tuna Salad",@"Roast Beef",@"Vegemite", nil];

self.breadTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"White",@"Whole Wheat", @"Rye", "@Sourdough", @"Seven Grain", nil];`
```

The fillingTypes array works but the breadTypes array crashes sending a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. When I step through it the breadTypes array says "Variable is not a CFArray". Why would one array work and the other fail?

Comment: The fact that you're trying to assign like `self.something` means that `something` is a declared property on your class. Are you declaring both properties as `NSArrays` ?

Comment: also instead of @"Sourdough" you have "@Sourdough"..

Comment: @Daniel: That is most definitely the problem. Xcode should have given the OP a warning.

Comment: People ignore warnings all the time. @Daniel, you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is you "@Sourdough" in there instead of @"Sourdough" which like the comments say generates a warning and will crash the program..the line should read

```
self.breadTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"White",@"Whole Wheat", @"Rye", @"Sourdough", @"Seven Grain", nil];
```